# How to get text inside Text component onPress in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to get text inside 'Text' component 'onPress' and set it to my component's state variable. Here is my code -

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
    return {   
        myStateVariable: 'New York'        
    }
},   
render: function(){
    return (  
        <Text onPress={()=>{
               this.setState({
                   myStateVariable: 'London' // This works fine
                   myStateVariable: this.children // This is not working
               });
             }  
        }>
            London
        </Text>
        <Text>{this.state.myStateVariable}</Text>
    );
}   
});
```

How to get the text inside 'Text' component dynamically?

Comment: this in this.children is actually pointing to MyComponent so it will return undefined.

Comment: The weird thing is, if you inspect this in this.setState in chrome dev tools, it is actually pointing to current 'Text' component object( with property children) and it does not have setState method, still it invokes setState method.

Comment: Is this an actual snippet or you wrote it to explain your original issue in a different fashion? I ask this because MyComponent already knows whats within the Text component. Why do you need to pull it back from Text? You can instead store the value in a class variable and access it.

Comment: @HazardouS - This code is almost similar. In my actual code, I have multiple Text components with cities rendered dynamically iterating over array. And on touch/press of particular Text component i want text inside it. It was not working, so I created this simple component for testing purpose but still facing same issue.

Comment: Added a possible pattern as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your feedback to my comment, you should try writing MyComponent like this -

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  onPress:function(i){
    let city = this.props.cities[i];
    // do something with city.
  },
  renderCities:function(){
    this.props.cities.map((city, i)=>{
      return <Text key={i} onPress={this.onPress.bind(this, i)}>{city}</Text>;
    });
  },
  render: function(){
      return (
        <div>
          {this.renderCities()}
        </div>
      );
  }   
});
```

Comment: It worked!. But I am not getting how it works? How did bind(this, i) solves this issue. Could you please explain more?

Comment: Sure. It works like this... you already have the array in the top level component, and every child element is linked with exactly one array element. So we can find which element was clicked if we simply send the element index to the click handler. The `bind` call returns a new function based on the context function, currying the given input as the default value of the original function parameter. So essentially we are creating "n" different functions, each sending a different index to the original function. A better alternative is to store the index in a prop & get it in the onPress handler.